# How to reference child elements in a Many-to-One relationship in ZF2 and Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form, many-to-one, zend-form-element

If I develop a project using ZF2 and Doctrine that hydrates an object with a Many-to-Many relationship similar this [Doctrine hydrator tutorial](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform), the parent fieldset would look like this:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Entity\BlogPost;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BlogPostFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('blog-post');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new BlogPost());

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'name' => 'title'
        ));

        $tagFieldset = new TagFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add(array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
            'name'    => 'tags',
            'options' => array(
                'count'           => 2,
                'target_element' => $tagFieldset
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'title' => array(
                'required' => true
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

and the form elements could be accessed in the view like this:

```
// edit.phtml:

// ...

$bpfs=$form->get('blog-post');
$tfss=$bpfs->get('tags')->getFieldsets();
$tfs=$tfss[0];

$tagName = $tfs->get('name');

// ...
```

However, if I want to use Many-to-One relationship, I'm not sure how to code the child elements.  In the `BlogPost Fieldset`, I assume that the `tag` element is no longer a collection because there will only be one of them.  Yet the tag is still a fieldset, so I guess that it goes into the `BlogPost Fieldset` like this:

```
$tagFieldset = new TagFieldset($objectManager);
$this->add(array(
    'name'    => 'tag',
    'options' => array(
        'target_element' => $tagFieldset
    )
));
```

(It's a single record, so I've changed the name to `tag`.  It's not a collection, nor does it seem to be any other ZF2 form elements, so I've dropped the `type` attribute statement.)

Then in the view, I attempt to access the form elements like this:

```
// edit.phtml:

// ...

$bpfs=$form->get('blog-post');
$tfs=$bpfs->get('tag')->getFieldsets();

$tagName = $tfs->get('name');

// ...
```

but this gives the error,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Form\Element::getFieldsets() in …
```

How should this be coded properly?

Answer (score 1):

Since `tag` is just one fieldset, you should do this:

```
$tfs=$bpfs->get('tag'); 
$tagName = $tfs->get('name');
```